# Attaching pictures to polygons in attribute table in batch using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, attribute-table, attachments

I use ArcGIS and I want to attach a picture of each polygon as raster in attribute table and I have 1900 of polygons.

Can somehow attach batch photos as raster that have same ID like polygons? It is possible?

I can do it one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have a Standard or Advanced license which will be needed to update the relationship feature class used by attachments.

There is a Help page entitled [Working with the Attachments geoprocessing tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000017z000000) which says:

> The geodatabase attachment tools offer a flexible environment for
>   batch processing of attachments. The attachment geoprocessing tools
>   should be used when a large number of files need to be attached in a
>   bulk operation.

I think you will need to use the [Generate Attachment Match Table (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000157000000) that is linked to there.